# "The connection was reset" in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-3.5

i have the submit form with multiple file upload control(java script).when i will run the code is working well and showing me the form proper.i will fill the information properly and also file upload is working ok.but on clicking of Submit button the Mozilla shows me the "The connection was reset" exception.but if i was not upload any file by using the file upload then it never shows me any error.it save in database properly.

i cant understand the problem please anybody help me out.
(sorry for English grammar).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file too big? Does the webserver accept files your size?

Comment: those files are image files and have resolution of 1002x3759.

Answer (score 2):

Try running with a sniffer (e.g. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)) - the output will give you a good idea as to the reason